# CSS footer links will not change to white

Tags: css, navigation, footer

Well I am finally almost done my first site. Except for the fact that my footer navigation links seems to be stuck on purple(default). I want to have the text display in white. Fixing the links anywhere else no problem. However, I can't seem to find anything in the code to change this. I have tried to review everything very carefully but I am stuck. Can someone please tell me what I may have missed?

```html
#footer{

    margin: 1px;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top:3px solid #107CBD;
    clear: both;

    color: #fff;
    line-height:23px;
    background-color:#505050;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
        font-size:12px;
    bottom:0px;
vertical-align:baseline:
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 3.5%;
    padding-bottom: 9.5%;
    background-color: #505050;
border-top:8px solid #107CBD;
position:fixed;
text-align:center;

}



#footer ul li a: hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#777;
}


#footer ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Noto-sans,sans serif;
    padding:2em 1em;
    color: #fff;

}


#footer ul li a: hover{

    background-color:#777777;

}

footer ul {
    width: 100%;
/*    margin-right: 25%;*/
}

footer ul li {
    float:0px;
    padding-right:2%;
    margin-right:3%;
    display: inline;
    font-family:Noto sans,sans serif;
    font-size:13px;

}

#footer ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Noto-sans',sans serif;
    padding:2em 1em;


}



div.footer-social{
     float:right;
    padding-right:10%;
    margin-right:5%;
    display: inline;
    margin-top:-2.8%;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more information like the html. You'd be better off copying the code into something like codepen so that we can see what's going on. Can you reproduce it there?

Comment: Here is the CodePen link:

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeWrgW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do like this:

```
footer ul li.changeBackground a 
{
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

See I think there is an error in your css.

```
vertical-align:baseline:
```

should be

```
vertical-align:baseline;
```

because of that rest of the css code may not be working

Comment: Tried this. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw in your codepen that you are using a HTML5 `<footer>` tag, but in your CSS you are (at least for those links) using `#footer` as an ID a few times:

```
#footer ul li a{ (etc.)
```

That might be the cause.